# how to grab value from checkbox and input with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, input

To echo the values from checked checkboxes , I am using this Ajax code:

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="PHP" /> PHP <br />  
 <input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="ASP" /> ASP <br />  
 <input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="JSP" /> JSP <br /> 

 <button type="button" class="values">Submit</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.values').click(function(){  
       var checkboxes_value = []; 

       $('.cb').each(function(){  
            //if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
            if(this.checked) {              
                 checkboxes_value.push($(this).val());                                                                               
            }  
       });                              
       checkboxes_value = checkboxes_value.toString(); 

       $.ajax({  
            url:"",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{ checkboxes_value:checkboxes_value },  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('.echo').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST["checkboxes_value"])) {  
  $result = $_POST["checkboxes_value"];  
  echo  '<br />'.$result.'<br />';
}
```

How can I echo the value of an input field according to the same procedure and in the same Ajax call?

So my HTML will be:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="PHP" /> PHP <br />  
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="ASP" /> ASP <br />  
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="JSP" /> JSP <br />  
<input type="text" class="text" value="" />

<button type="button" class="values">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Please clear your question. Do you want your input field value based on checked checkbox? e.g. if we select PHP checkbox, in Input field we will get PHP like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you can do that in this way

```
<input type="text" class="text" value="" />
```

Your jquery

```
$('.values').click(function(){  
       var checkboxes_value = []; 
        var inputval=$(".text").val();//getting value of input field
       $('.cb').each(function(){  
            //if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
            if(this.checked) {              
                 checkboxes_value.push($(this).val());                                                                               
            }  
       });                              
       checkboxes_value = checkboxes_value.toString(); 

       $.ajax({  
            url:"",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{ checkboxes_value:checkboxes_value,inputval:inputval},  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('.echo').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
    });
```

Your php code

```
if(isset($_POST["checkboxes_value"]) && isset($_POST["inputval"]) ) {  
  $result = $_POST["checkboxes_value"];  
  echo  '<br />'.$result.'<br />';
echo  '<br />'.$_POST["inputval"].'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure why you are using AJAX, since you are only returning the value that is sent via AJAX.  What about doing like this:

```js
$('.values').click(function(){
    var checkboxes_value = []; 

    $('input').each(function(){
        if(this.checked) {
            checkboxes_value.push($(this).val());
        }else if($(this).hasClass('text')){
            checkboxes_value.push($(this).val());
        }
    });                              

    checkboxes_value = checkboxes_value.toString(); 
    $('.echo').html(checkboxes_value);
});
```

```css
div.echo{margin-top:50px;background:wheat;padding:50px;border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="PHP" /> PHP <br />  
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="ASP" /> ASP <br />  
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="JSP" /> JSP <br />  
<input type="text" class="text" value="" />

<button type="button" class="values">Submit</button>

<div class="echo"></div>
```

Notes:

1. Since the elements you wish to test are all `input` elements, you can just loop through all input elements.
2. There is no need for the AJAX, since it only echoes back what it received. You can do what you want just in javascript/jQuery.

Comment: I agree if it was only returning the values. But i need the values in php, So i tested it only with the echo if it works. Now i can bind the values to a php variable and do some other things with it. But, you are right, for just outputting html, i didn't need ajax.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for that response - I thought it might be something like that but one is never sure so thought I should mention that, jic.

Answer (score 0):

A simpe foreach loop perhaps?

```
if(isset($_POST["checkboxes_value"])) {  
   foreach($_POST['checkboxes_value'] as $result){
       echo '<input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="' . $result . '" /> ' . $result . ' <br />';
   }
}
```

Comment: I already can echo the values of the chosen checkboxes. But i want to add the value of the input field extra

Comment: you want the value of the text input to contain all the values of the checkboxes posted? i don't quite understand what you need.

Comment: no, i just wanted the value of the input extra. So echo the values of the checkboxes **and** echo the value of the input